# exporting data frame to csv file in python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I want to export my dataframe to a csv file. normally I want my dataframe as 2 columns but when I export it, in csv file there is only one column and the data is separated with comma.

m is one column and s is another.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'MSE':[m], 'SSIM': [s]})
```

to append new data frames I used below function and save data to csv file:.

```
with open('test.csv', 'a+') as f:        
    df.to_csv(f, header=False)    

print(df)
```

when I print dataframe on console output looks like:

> > ```
> >     MSE      SSIM  
> >
> > 0  0.743373  0.843658
> > ```

but in csv file a column looks like: here first is index, second is m and last one is s. I want them in 3 seperate columns

```
0,1.1264238582283046,0.8178900901529639
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: A single column in what? When opened in Excel?

Comment: Can we see what the data looks like? Can't really help without seeing any more info

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, in excel file in a single row all my data is in a single column. I want them to be in 3 seperate columns.

Comment: I suspect that it's an issue with excel because there doesn't appear to be an issue with the approach. Otherwise I think you'll need to post a reproducible example for us to be able to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your excel setting is most likely `;` (semi-colon). Use:

```
df.to_csv(f, header=False, sep=';')
```